# How to get multiple rows with order by and limit

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a mysql table, the structure of that table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salary_log` (`salary_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `salary` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `create_date` date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`salary_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `salary_log` (`salary_id`, `salary`, `name`, `create_date`) VALUES (1, 5000, 'a', '2013-05-02'), (2, 8000, 'a', '2013-05-08'), (3, 4500, 'b', '2013-05-10'), (4,6000, 'c', '2013-05-08'), (5, 8000, 'b', '2013-05-17');
```

From the above table i need to fetch the latest records of each employee. I tried below query :

```
SELECT * FROM `salary_log` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `create_date` DESC;
```

But it returns be wrong data. Can someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s1.* 
FROM `salary_log` AS s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MAX(create_date) AS maxDate
    FROM salary_log
    GROUP BY `name`
) AS s2  ON s1.name        = s2.name 
        AND s1.create_date = s2.maxDate;
```